# Center element relative to wrapping inline span

Tags: javascript, css

How can i show a number in center underneath a underlined text?

My code works for simple cases, but when the text wraps, the number is no longer centered under the text:

[image: current]

I want something like this instead:

[image: required]

This is my code that is have written so far.

```css
p {
  line-height: 28px;
}
.bottom_bullet_spn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
}
.bottom_bullet {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 9px !important;
  top: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="question mb10  other_question ">
  <div style="vertical-align: top;padding-bottom: 1em;">

    <div class="questions_passage passage_content_1804">
      <p>Lorem ip<span style="display: inline; text-decoration: underline;" class="bottom_bullet_spn">sum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore mag<span class="bottom_bullet" data-order="1">1</span></span>na
        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui <span style="display: inline; text-decoration: underline;" class="bottom_bullet_spn">officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<span class="bottom_bullet" data-order="2">2</span></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/grLe7snj/1/)

The number 2 is centered correctly  but number 1 is not centered.

**Javascript solution will also work**

Comment: your link is not working.!

Comment: I am a beginner here. thanks man :)

Comment: Are you looking for accurate centering? 1 is almost centered.

Comment: Yes i want accurate centering. Like number 2

Comment: Did you think about resizing your window..., don't use absolute...

Comment: @adnanahmed What is the case when the underlined text wraps in two lines?

Comment: @KK thats exactly my concern. This issue only happens when underlined text overflows to two lines.

Comment: What is "centered" mean in case of two-line span? The cented of the first line of the center between the beginning of the first and the end of the second?

Comment: @dfsq centered mean **center of underline text**

Comment: I like this question, but I suspect there's not going to be a CSS-only solution. To be 100% clear, can you confirm that you want the number to be directly under the midpoint of the text, wherever that happens to be? E.g. if the text starts halfway along one line 1 and ends halfway along line 2, the number should be at the very right of line 1, or the left of line 2 (although technically it should probably be split over the two lines)... Correct?

Comment: I also agree that this is an interesting question.

Comment: @CupawnTae yes i want it exactly as you explained.

Comment: @adnanahmed I added a couple of images to help explain - please feel free to edit/remove my changes as you see fit

Comment: @adnanahmed one more thing - would you accept a javascript solution? Not that I have anything specific in mind, but if it would work for you, you could mention it in the question and add a javascript tag to get more attention/options.

Comment: JS solution will also work.

Answer (score 0):

If window resizing is not your concern, then you may try this:

```
.bottom_bullet {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 9px !important;
    top: 0;
    margin:10px auto 0 auto; //you can also use margin:0 auto; But text will overlap.
    width:20px;
}
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/grLe7snj/2/

But if you are worried about resizing, then I would suggest you to place that small number at the end of the underlined text. In that way, you will solve your problems and also it will be good on user part too. Generally you place such numbers at the end of the text or rarely at the start(refer wikipedia)

In this case:

```
.bottom_bullet {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 9px !important;
    top: 0;
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    width:20px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/grLe7snj/3/